# Pop up tab in Google Chrome claiming a virus is present on the computer

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware

I have Chrome set to "Do not allow any site to show pop-ups", yet when browsing a regularly visited forum I occasionally get a new tab open claiming the computer has a virus and asking me to call a number to fix it. It is not possible to close this window, except through Task Manager, End Task. Disabling Javascript for that site seems to stop it popping up, but I haven't tested it enough to be completely sure.

Just to be on the safe side I ran AdwCleaner and Malwarebytes Anti-malware scans. The AdwCleaner scan showed that the Search Provider on Chrome had been changed to "uk.ask.com". Malwarebytes Anti-malware came up clean.

Should I contact the forum owner to inform them that they probably have a compromised advert on their page? My guess is that this is the most likely cause of the problem.

I include a screenshot of the window which opened:

[image]

Comment: Why is it not possible to close? Do you not get an option in browser to prevent the site asking the same question? As to informing them, that has nothing to do with us so up to you. To confirm it opens a new window,  not a new tab?

Comment: As far as I remember as soon as you click the "ok" button another message box pops up, to be honest though since it happened the first time I've just always killed chrome through the task manager.

Comment: @user1977132 - You can close the window by closing the tab and/or using `CTRL+F4` which closes the active tab not Chrome entirely.  You do understand, the warning itself, is 100% fake right?  The notification itself is generated by javascript which is the reason your settings are not preventing it.  The "Security Esstinals` window is fake, the notification window at the bottom right is an image, and the notification was generated by javascript.

Comment: @Ramhound, as always, good advice, but the issue also appears to be that the pop up is allowed. This is why I asked about the new tab, to see if the new window opens as a new window or a new tab. It's not clear, and it may  not be a "popup" but an overlay (although clearly a new window is open, but there is only 1 tab)

Comment: @Dave - the javascript forced Chrome to open a new tab, again, with javascript.  There is no actual Chrome window by the way, everything is either an image or generated by javascript ( which is different then say an actual chrome ui window ).

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, but if it was a new tab, then why is it the only tab and only 1 window in the screen shot :) (I updated my comment after you replied)

Comment: @Dave - My educated guess?  It was seperated from the other chrome instances, to reduce the amount of work needed, when the author blured PII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Chrome set to "Do not allow any site to show pop-ups", yet when
>   browsing a regularly visited forum I occasionally get a new tab open
>   claiming the computer has a virus and asking me to call a number to
>   fix it.

This is because the notification is generated by Javascript and this particular setting has no effect on Javascript.

> It is not possible to close this window, except through Task Manager,
>   End Task.

This is incorrect.  You can close the window by closing the active tab.  You can acomplish this by using `CTRL+F4`.

> Disabling Javascript for that site seems to stop it popping up

This is because the entire page is javascript and a static image.

Comment: "Should I contact the forum owner to inform them that they probably have a compromised advert on their page?" - This isn't a question we can answer here at Superuser.  It is out of scope.  Any answer to this particular sub-question would be my opionion.

Comment: I am suprised that OP does'nt get the option to prevent the window/website requesting the same question over and over

Comment: @Dave - The question with regards to the behavior is a little light on specifics.  It doesn't matter really though.  The majority of these "notifications" are static images and use javascript to prevent the tab from being closed, since Chrome uses seperates processes for each tab, hitting `CTRL+F4` closes just the active tab.  I have seen hundreds of these notifications over the years.